# Rails - Table <TR> - Add filter with a button / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to implement a filter on my table by clicking on a button

I got a table here :

```
    <div class="table-container">
        <table class="table table-filter">
        <tbody>
         <% if current_user %>
         <% @book.each do |book| %>
         <tr data-status = "###">   
<!-- I would like to implement <%= book.style %> inside that data-status, to filter on the type of books   -->
           <td><%= book.name %></td>
           <td> <%= book.author %></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>
     </table>
   </div>
```

And a Script to filter when i click on the button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-filter" data-target="novel">PC</button>
```

Here is the script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {   

    $('.btn-filter').on('click', function () {
      var $target = $(this).data('target');
      if ($target != 'all') {
        $('.table tr').css('display', 'none');
        $('.table tr[data-status="' + $target + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $('.table tr').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    });
   });
</script>
```

I dont know how to pass the value of the book type , inside the Data-status = <% book.style %> and even when i put a text value , like Novel , it doesnt filter on the table.

I dont really know where am I wrong and im looking for help on this. Do I need to use a content_tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply:

```
<tr data-status = "<%= book.style %>">
```

Comment: Yes i was trying that, and it's working , but i dont really know why my table is empty when i click on that button , maybe the JS or my CSS is wrong ,thanks for that confirmation :) I gonna investigate further

Comment: I found the solution , I have to work with IDs and not string on that Data-Status, when it's not well written , all in caps for example , it doesnt work.